# I can not upload data to a VirtualStringTree

Tags: c++builder-6

I have a form with a TPageControl that has two tabs. In each of them there is a TVirtualStringTree and I have defined these two structures:

```
typedef struct tagTTreeMun
{
     AnsiString Municipio;
     int Padron;
     int Censo;
     double Relacion;
     int Codigo;
} TTreeMun, *PTreeMun;

typedef struct tagTTreePro
{
     AnsiString Proceso;
     int Padron;
     int Censo;
     double Relacion;
     int Codigo;
}TTreePro, *PTreePro;
```

I know: they are almost the same; then I explain it. The first one is loaded from four nested querys and it does it without any problem, but the second one ... There's no way!

To load this second I need two querys:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM Elections ORDER BY Date DESC
```

that field Date contains only the year and runs without any problem.

```
SELECT A.Codigo, B.Name, SUM (C.Padron) Padron, SUM (C.Censo) Census, A.Closed
  FROM Elections A, Process B, HisElec C
 WHERE A.CodPrv = (SELECT Literal FROM Installation WHERE Label = 'Province')
   AND A.CodPrv = B.CodPrv AND B.Codigo = A.Process AND A.Closed = 1
   AND A.CodPrv = C.CodPrv AND A.Codigo = C.Election
   AND A. Date =: Date
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 5
 UNION
SELECT A.Codigo, B.Name, SUM (C.Padron) Padron,
       (SELECT SUM (Census) FROM Tables WHERE CodPrv = (SELECT Literal FROM Installation WHERE Label = 'Province')) Census,
       A.Closed
  FROM Elections A, Process B, Dl01 C
 WHERE A.CodPrv = (SELECT Literal FROM Installation WHERE Label = 'Province')
   AND A.CodPrv = B.CodPrv AND A.Process = B.Code AND A.Closed = 0
   AND A. Date =: Date
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 5
 ORDER BY 1 DESC, 3
```

It also runs without problems or errors. The problem comes when trying to pass that data to the corresponding TVirtualStringTree.

```
PTreePro DatPro;
PVirtualNode Node1, Node2, Node3, Node4;

LisPro->NodeDataSize = sizeof (TTreePro);
LisPro->BeginUpdate ();
LisPro->Clear ();
for (;! qTemp1->Eof; qTemp1->Next ())
{
     Node1 = LisPro->AddChild (NULL);
     DatPro = (PTreePro) LisPro->GetNodeData (Node1);
     DatPro->Process = IntToStr(qTemp1->FieldByName ("Date")->AsInteger);

     qTemp2->Close ();
     qTemp2->ParamByName ("Date")->AsInteger = qTemp1->FieldByName("Date")->AsInteger;
     qTemp2->Open ();
     for (;! qTemp1->Eof; qTemp1->Next())
     {
          Node2 = LisPro->AddChild(Node1);
          DatPro = (PTreePro)LisPro->GetNodeData(Node2);
          DatPro->Process = qTemp1->FieldByName("Name")
          [...]
     }
 }
```

When trying to create that Node1 in this query, the lines Node1 = ... and DatPro = (PTreePro) ... are executed without major problem, except that Node1, after running the AddChild, has a NULL value and therefore, from then on, it can only give an error because when trying to give value to Process, it automatically gives an execution error.

I have tried putting the load of each of the trees in a different function, by isolating code; I have tried with the same structure (in the end they are identical) or as in the example with two structures, to change the order of execution. For more tests that I have done I am not able to load both trees, in LisPro I ALWAYS do the same to me.

Comment: `AddChild()` cannot return a NULL pointer. Neither can `GetNodeData()` when `NodeDataSize > 0`. Something else is going on.

Comment: I do not know what I will have done. To prove I was doing wrong, I opened a new form and copied both the TVirtualStringTree and the code I was using, and it worked perfectly! In short: I copied what was in this new form and now it works without errors. I do not understand anything.